# Java streams set each attribute of object List with another List

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I currently have a list of objects like

```
List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Where Foo is:

```
public class Foo {
    public Bar bar;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Now with another `List<Bar> barList` I wanted to set each `Bar` element to each inner `Foo.Bar` element of `fooList` using Java streams.

I tried to do that using `map` function with `setBar` but I cannot call a "set" inside `map`.

Comment: What about `barList.forEach(b -> fooList.forEach(f -> f.setBar(b)));`

Comment: Unfortunately, that involves excess looping and unnecessary sets.  For `n` elements in each list you are doing a total of `(n*n) sets` when all you need is `n` sets.  It's a nested loop.

Comment: I don't know why the down votes. Is it because I took one day to provide a feedback on the answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this.  It returns a new List of altered `Foo` objects.  The original is changed too.  I could have used peek to invoke the change but using `peek` in that fashion is considered poor practice.

```
IntStream.range(0, fooList.size()).mapToObj(i -> {
    fooList.get(i).setBar(barList.get(i));
               return fooList.get(i);})
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I would not use streams for this but a simple for loop.  For example,

```
for (int i = 0; i < fooList.size(); i++) {
    fooList.get(i).setBar(barList.get(i));
}
```

or with an enhanced forloop and local index.

```
int i = 0;
for (Foo f : fooList) {
    f.setBar(barList.get(i++));
}
```

These solutions presume there is a one-to-one ordered mapping of `fooList` elements to `barList` elements.

Comment: Thank you! The simple the better. Your answer pointed me to the right way. Cheers!